# Magento 2.1.7 add CMS page multiselect to CMS page

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, adminform, cms-pages, multiselect

I'm new to Magento 2 and I'm trying to add a multiselect of all (for now) CMS pages to the CMS pages in Magento 2. What I mean by this is that when creating/editing a CMS page, there should be an extra field with all (other) CMS pages from which you can select multiple (or just one or none at all), just like you have a multiselect for the **Store View** field.
I have got it to work to render the multiselect and you can select multiple, but upon saving it shows a message that "something" went wrong.
Example of the fields: [image: CMS page multiselect]

I've also created an upgrade script which has successfully created an extra field in the **cms_page** table. I can still save pages, but only when I don't select any CMS pages.

Here's my //view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="search_engine_optimisation">
        <field name="redirect_to">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Redirect to pages</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">redirect_to</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? For some reason, I've gotten it to work but it would only save one, never multiple, but I can't seem to reproduce that anymore.

What I'd like to achieve is for it to save all selected options as a JSON encoded string with the store id as key and the URL as value. How would I go about doing this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change option class for your requirement. So make following way.

Change **<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page</item>**

to

**<item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Page</item>**

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

class Page extends \Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Page
{
    /**
     * To option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if (!$this->options) {
            $emptyOption[] = [
                'value' => 'all',
                'label' => 'All'
            ];
            $this->options = $this->collectionFactory->create()->toOptionIdArray();

            $this->options = array_merge($emptyOption, $this->options);
        }

        return $this->options;
    }
}
```

Now you can able to see 'All' option inside multiselect element.

**For save:**

Create a plugin for this:
VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page\PostDataProcessor">
        <plugin name="PostDataProcessor_Save" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Page\PostDataProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="DataProvider_Load" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Page\DataProvider" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/PostDataProcessor.php

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Page;

class PostDataProcessor
{
    public function aroundFilter(
        \Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page\PostDataProcessor $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $data
    ) {

        if(isset($data['redirect_to']) && ($data['redirect_to'])) {
            $data['redirect_to'] = json_encode($data['redirect_to']);
        }

        return $proceed($data);
    }
}
```

**For edit:**

VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Model/Page/DataProvider.php

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Page;


class DataProvider
{
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetData(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if (is_array($result)) {
            foreach ($result as &$item) {
                if(isset($item['redirect_to']) && ($item['redirect_to'])) {
                    $item['redirect_to'] = json_decode($item['redirect_to']);
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works great for editing already existing CMS pages, but when I want to create a new CMS page, it throws the following error:

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment, it got cut of, here's the full comment:
This works great for editing already existing CMS pages, but when I want to create a new CMS page, it throws the following error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/app/code/Phpro/CmsRedirect/Plugin/Model/Page/DataProvider.php on line 25`. It looks like somethiing was wrong wit the `foreach ($result as &$item) {`. To circumvent this I wrote a check around that to check if there is a `$result` and now it works great.
Many, many thanks for the quick and elaborate response!